How to generate PDF's that have expandable fields (on hover or click shows the extra text)
I use vue and jsPDF with domtoimage that makes my html page a jpeg and saves it to an adobe acrobat pdf
I need to generate PDF's with dynamic data and sometimes the text in certain fields are quite long either cutting off or spreading line height so much that data is lost at the bottom of the page.
I setup my page using
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: fr
This sets the width of each column leaving the height to adjust for text
I currently set the lines per page for a report, however as i am working with dynamic data this often causes problems.
I need a better solution and if i could export a multilayer pdf that would essentially accordian/expand on hover or click where the text goes over that would be amazing.
I have very limited experience with creating pdfs dynamically and am open to any suggestions, i have tried counting the length of strings and adjusting the layout of the pdfs to accomidate the outlyers but this isnt exactly what i want.
